# Compute key digest for multi sig wallet

Tags: wallet, iri-legacy-api, private-key

Reading [Generating Secure Multisig Addresses (for hot wallets and cold storage)](https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/docs/generating-secure-multisig-addresses-hot-and-coldwallet), I see the term "key digest".

1. Is this key a private key associated with an address?
2. How to compute the digest?
3. Since both party can have many addresses, and many private keys, which keys' digests are good for use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key digest is a string of trytes that is generated using a seed and a private key.

For multisig, each co-signer provides a key digest, and all of these key digests are used to create a multisig address.
The co-signers can safely share their key digest with other co-signers so that each one can independently validate the multisig address.

See [this article](https://github.com/iotaledger/wiki/blob/master/multisigs.md) for more info.

[edit] You can create a key digest with the JavaScript API:

iota.multisig.getDigest(seed, index) Generates the digest value of a key.

seed: String, Tryte encoded seed index

index: Integer, Index of the public/private key pair that you want to use.

Returns
String - key digest represented in trytes

Comment: I also read that, but that article did not explain how one can make a digest either.

Comment: You can create a digest with the JavaScript API:

iota.multisig.getDigest(seed, index)

Generates the digest value of a key.

**Input**
seed: String Tryte encoded seed
index: 'Int’ Index of the private key.

**Returns**
String - digest represented in trytes.

Index is the index of the public/private key pair that you want to use

Comment: Please include those information with [edit] into your answer. as they are quite important to answer the *how to compute* part of the question.

Comment: also what's the criteria in choosing the index? Can an used address's private key be used?

Comment: Always increment the index after a transaction has been sent from a multisig address. This information is in the article I link to in my answer.

Comment: This scheme makes address management difficult. I need to have an Excel table tracking which addresses are used, which are addresses are never used but reserved for multi-sig.